# jQuery/css/html: scrollable table with fixed header

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollable

I know this question has been asked several times but I couldn't find a satisfying, x-browser solution yet.

I thought the easiest way to accomplish a scrollable table with fixed header should be using 2 tables:
(1 for header, 1 for the content) and sync them. I've tried that but there's always slight glitches in the layout (between Firefox and e.g. IE8)

So I'm looking for a simple and bulletproof solution - anyone who can help me?